# API call result string not able to retrieve in html page

Tags: angular

I am trying to call one Spring boot REST API from Angular component and trying to display the result string by using `alert()`. When I am trying to display, it is giving the error

```
message: "Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0"
```

The result of this API is successfully giving back the string "Permission Updated Successfully" at Postman.

MY component code is like the following in my .ts file,

```
this.manageuserService.modifyUserPermissionApiMethod(this.modificationObj)
  .subscribe((data:any)=> {alert(data);});
```

Where have I gone wrong in implementing this?

Comment: Does the response you get include the quotes? Otherwise, this is not valid JSON.

Comment: @Henry- No I am only getting as string without quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Angular HTTP Client by default expects response type to be '**application/json**', but in your case the response from the server it is not a valid JSON ( i suppose it is just simple text - 'text/plain').

You should pass an additional parameter `responseType: 'text'`, please check the following link:
https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data